# join does not return expected result in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I have data that looks like,

```
id  tag value
1   C   2000
1   C   2000
2   C   2000
1   D   1500
1   D   1200
3   D   2500
```

I have a requirement where i should get a net value based on the tags *sum(D)- sum(C)*

My query,

```
 select 'C' as tag,t1.Debit - t.Credit as result from
   (SELECT `tag` , sum(value) as Credit
    FROM
        test
    WHERE
        tag = 'C' group by `tag` ) t
    join (
         SELECT `tag` , sum(value) as Debit
    FROM
        test
    WHERE
        tag = 'D' group by `tag`
)t1;
```

gives the result as,

```
tag result
C   -800 -- (5200 - 6000)
```

which the correct result given the data above.

However should all tags be *D* the query returns no values,but i expect the result as 11200 which is the total of D.

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c0ab940ced10c4f3c09cb3d9b6b48c8d)

Comment: Do you have only these two tags C or D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT   SUM(CASE WHEN tag='D' THEN value ELSE 0 END)
       - SUM(CASE WHEN tag='C' THEN value ELSE 0 END)
FROM test
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a95ca17cf18c5a8d15abf8fd8514c4e0)

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c1a8128438efc5cf7affee810a204e9):

```
select sum(CASE WHEN tag='D' THEN value ELSE 0 END)-sum(CASE WHEN tag='C' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as val from test;
```

If you are going to have only 'D' or 'C' as tag.

then

```
select sum(CASE WHEN tag='D' THEN value ELSE -value END) as val from test;
```